# Sorting an ArrayList of ChainHashMap

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I am having difficulty sorting an ArrayList of ChainHashMaps. Each HashMap that the ArrayList holds only has one entry that contains a String and Integer. So, to sort this, I created a separate method where I take all of the values of the ArrayList HashMaps and sort them. This method that I created works perfectly. The part that I am having trouble with is bringing it back together and creating an ArrayList of ChainHashMaps(with String and Integer) that is sorted.
Here is the method that I have so far:

```
public static ArrayList<ChainHashMap<String, Integer>> sortWords(ArrayList<Integer> values, ArrayList<ChainHashMap<String, Integer>> a){
    ArrayList<ChainHashMap<String, Integer>> outcome = new ArrayList<ChainHashMap<String, Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++){
            for (Object k : a.get(j).keySet()){
                String word = (String) k;
                if (values.get(i).equals(a.get(j).get(word))){
                    ChainHashMap<String, Integer> oneEntry = new ChainHashMap<String, Integer>();
                    oneEntry.put(word, a.get(j).get(word));
                    outcome.add(oneEntry);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

This method takes an ArrayList of Integers (this is the ArrayList that I have sorted separately with just the Integer values of the ChainHashMaps) and an ArrayList of ChainHashMaps (String and Integer. This is the original ArrayList that needs to be sorted). It returns an ArrayList of these ChainHashMaps that is sorted.

When I run this, it somehow ends up not terminating in eclipse. This is for homework so I don't want to use any in-built java methods to solve it. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is ChainHashMap and where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

If I test it with `HashMap` it seems to work, I don't see what's wrong apart from some performance issues and the fact that I have no clue what `ChainHashMap` is.

> **Example.** *with 1,2,3,4*
>
> input to be sorted: `[{first=1}, {fourth=4}, {third=3}, {second=2}]`
>
> input sorted integers: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
>
> output (correct): `[{first=1}, {second=2}, {third=3}, {fourth=4}]`

**Performance**

The sorting method is not really optimised for speed and readability, it does a lot more iterations then necessary. Some quick wins are:

- if you find the result in the inner j-loop, break out of it with `break;`
- since your map has only 1 entry, you don't need the `for (Object k : a.get(j).keySet())`

**HashMap code with unit test**

The code with HashMap and the test (without assertions) looks as follows:

```
@Test
public void testMap(){

    List<Map<String, Integer>> toBeSorted = Arrays.asList( new HashMap(){{ put("first", 1); }}, new HashMap(){{ put("fourth", 4); }}, new HashMap(){{ put("third", 3); }}, new HashMap(){{ put("second", 2); }} );
    List<Integer> sortedList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);

    ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>> maps = sortWords(sortedList, toBeSorted);

    System.out.print(maps);
}

public ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>> sortWords(List<Integer> values, List<Map<String, Integer>> a){
    ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>> outcome = new ArrayList<Map<String, Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++){
            for (Object k : a.get(j).keySet()){
                String word = (String) k;
                if (values.get(i).equals(a.get(j).get(word))){
                    Map<String, Integer> oneEntry = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    oneEntry.put(word, a.get(j).get(word));
                    outcome.add(oneEntry);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return outcome;
}
```

The output is correct:

```
[{first=1}, {second=2}, {third=3}, {fourth=4}]
```